# Classification result from SAGA GIS shifted by 5 meters if used in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, r, saga, accuracy

I use a band composite of 10 Sentinel-2 bands for my classifications. If I use the same composite in SAGA to make a classification this classification result is shifted by 5 meters to the left and to the bottom. [image]

Since I used the same band composite I do not understand why is the result from SAGA shifted when should be exactly above the other result from ArcGIS.

Comment: Shifted how much? Less than a pixel? And what was the geometry of the input rasters you composited? Were they all the same? Has anything been interpolated to a common geometry? This is not the same as using the same CRS. Not sure how we can help without sample data.

Comment: I edited my question and I hope it is more clear now. It is shifted 5 meters to the left and to the bottom and this is half a pixel. The rasters have been all the same I resampled and reprojected them in SNAP. If I do a classification in SNAP and then use it in ArcGIS it perfectly matches the ArcGIS result.

Comment: The origin coordinates define the alignment of the raster array. Some software treat the lower-left corner of the cell as the origin and some the center of the lower-left cell. As I recall, ESRI has always used the lower-left corner and not the centroid. At 10m resolution, this would explain the 5m offset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I hope I can find a option in SAGA to change the alignment.